# Is it possible to schedule the deletion of rows from a mysql table based on their creation date?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have a table containing chat-rooms created by users.I want my database server to automatically delete the rooms that are 1 day old.I know I can manually write a query to do this, I don't know how to make the database server delete the rows by its own.

[image: Table]

Comment: are you aware of mysql event scheduler https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html ?

Comment: Easiest to schedule a job to run on the server on a regular basis (if you have access) otherwise, a similar job can be set up on a client. Do you have access to the server?

Comment: i have acces to both the node js server and the mysql server

Comment: so it would be best to make a method on the node js server that executes once a day and runs a query that deletes rows older than 1 day?

Answer (score 0):

You can relate this question to database archive process where you can archive old data (which can be in day/month/year) and this archived data can be stored into another table which is good for backup purpose.
**This can be done by simple cron job.**

> As you might aware of cron job which is a time based job scheduler in
>   unix system to run automatically at a specified time and date. - 
>   https://kb.iu.edu/d/afiz

You can follow these step to write a shell script which includes mysql query for database archiving

1. Create archive table on same database - for backup purpose

> create table archive_table like main_table;

2. Insert old data into Archive table so you can use it in future if needed, in this example it will insert one day old data (you can change it according to your requirements)

> insert into archive_table select * from main_table where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(),  INTERVAL 1  DAY);

3. Delete same data from your main table by running below query

> delete from main_table where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW() - INTERVAL 1  DAY);

Build your script file by using upper queries (please refer shell script syntax to build script) . 
open your crontab list by running below command

> crontab -l

and put below command into crontab list. change this command according path to script file. use for [crontab-guru](https://crontab.guru/) reference and put

> 0 0 * * * cd **path-to-script-file** && sh **path-to-shell-script-file**